# What are some large or small mathematical constants?

Tags: big-list, constants

I understand this question is a bit vague, but I would like to know about *notable* mathematical constants that are *large or small*, and I clarify what I mean now:

- Notable, as in **not a product, sum, exponentiation, or other operation on other constants simply for the sake that they are a product, sum, exponentiation, or operation on other constants.** So, not $e^{e^2}$ or $\pi^{50\gamma}$. Also, not large or small for the sake of being large or small (no googolplex.)
- Large or small, as in larger than 100 or less than 0.1.

*Motivation*: there is one number on Wikipedia's [list of mathematical constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_constants) page larger than 100, and three less than 0.1, and I am *stunned* by this normality! We need better representation of large and small constants.

Comment: Related: [Why are all the interesting constants so small?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/120780/856)

Comment: Have you seen the [ebyte.it list of Mathematical Constants and Sequences](http://www.ebyte.it/library/educards/constants/MathConstants.html#Rie0) and the associated sublinks?

Comment: [Liouville's Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LiouvillesConstant.html) was the first decimal constant to be proven transcendental (by Liouville in 1850). It is slightly larger than 0.1.

Comment: It's an interesting question. But I think you should try to make more precise the definition of what is a (notable) constant. As there lies the answer.

Answer (score 3):

> - Constant $\sigma_3$: The non-zero constant with smallest absolute  value stated in *[Mathematical Constants](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521818052)*, Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications, vol. 94 is 
>     \begin{align*}
>   \color{blue}{\sigma_3=-0.000\,111\,158\,2...}
>   \end{align*}

We can find in section 2.21 *Stieltjes Constants*:
\begin{align*}
\sigma_n=\sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{\rho^n}=
\begin{cases}
-\frac{1}{2}\ln(4\pi)+\frac{\gamma_0}{2}+1=0.023\,095\,708\,9\ldots&n=1,\\
-\frac{\pi^2}{8}+\gamma_0^2+2\gamma_1+1=-0.046\,154\,317\,2\ldots&n=2,\\
-\frac{7\zeta{3}}{8}+\gamma_0^3+3\gamma_0\gamma_1+\frac{3\gamma_2}{2}+1=\color{blue}{-0.000\,111\,158\,2\ldots}&n=3,
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
where    each sum is over all nontrivial zeros $\rho$ of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(z)$. The constants $\gamma_n$ come from the Laurent expansion in a neighborhood of its simple pole at $z=1$:
\begin{align*}
\zeta(z)=\frac{1}{z-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\gamma_n(z-1)^n.
\end{align*}

> - Stieltjes Constant $\gamma_{100\,000}$:
>
>   The coefficients $\gamma_n$ can be proved to satisfy
>     \begin{align*}
>   \gamma_n=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{\ln(k)^n}{k}-\frac{\ln(m)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)
>   \end{align*}
>     In particular $\gamma_0=\gamma=0.577\,215\,664\,9\ldots$ is the *[Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant)*. A *somewhat* larger constant of this family is the constant
>     \begin{align*}
>   \color{blue}{\gamma_{100\,000}=1.991\,927\,306\,3\ldots\times10^{83\,432}}
>   \end{align*}
>     which is stated *[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants)*.

Answer (score 2):

I'll start. [Ramanujan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number) (sometimes called the Hermite-Ramanujan constant) is a large transcendental number that is *very* close to an integer. It is expressible as
$$R = e^{\pi\sqrt{163}} = 262537412640768743.99999999999925\dots \approx 640320^3+744$$

Answer (score 1):

Some are very arbitrary, like $\pi^\pi$.
If that number is considered important enough for inclusion in the wiki list, then why not $\pi^{\pi^{\pi}}$, $e^e$, $e^{e^e}$, and many other tetrations?

Comment: If you'd call them arbitrary, I wouldn't say they're notable, so they would not be considered important enough for inclusion.

Comment: But they are included, e.g. $\pi^\pi$.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean I'd consider every constant on that list notable. I was just concerned with the fact that, despite it being so large a list, there were still very few 'large/small' constants.

Answer (score 1):

As to why notable constants are generally small, I think it is best to think about what they mean and where they come from.

For example, pi is the ratio between a circles radius and its circumference. These are 2 relatively "similar" (as in the ratio between the 2 is relatively small) distances, so pi is a relatively small number.

Gamma is approximately the difference between the harmonic series in respect to n and ln(n). Both ln and the harmonic series grow very slowly and close together (about a gamma distance apart!) but both diverge.

Similar philosophies can be applied to most commonly used numbers like these.

Comment: If you think about it your argument is a  tautology. You have to do a bit more work to estimate for example that $\pi <4$ and that $\gamma<1$. And with more work you can make these estimates precise.

Answer (score 1):

[Wyler's constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WylersConstant.html) is defined as 
\begin{align}\alpha_{\small{W}}&=\frac{9}{8\pi^4}\left(\frac{\pi^5}{2^45!}\right)^{1/4}\\&=0.0072973481300\dots\\&=
\frac{1}{137.0360824\dots}
\end{align}

(Wyler 1969; OEIS [A180872](http://oeis.org/A180872)), which at the [time it was proposed](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.3022875), agreed with experiment to within $\pm1.5$ ppm for the value of the fine structure constant $\alpha$ in physics.

The constant is a transcendental number.