# What is the smallest number with any mathematical value of property?

Tags: real-numbers

I know that Graham's number is the biggest number ever used in a mathematical demonstration. Does a similarly unimaginably small number, with any worth of note mathematical property, exist?

Please note that I'm talking about the smallest absolute value, so I don't care about negative numbers, only positive real numbers (and I also don't really care about zero).

Comment: The number zero.

Comment: Or if you are only interested in positive integers, one.

Comment: @LeeMosher Yeah, I guess you're right, but that's not what I really meant

Comment: 1 divided by Graham's number. Even better: Graham's number to the power of negative Graham's number. Even better: ...

Comment: See [What is the smallest constant that has explicitly appeared in a published paper?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98205/what-is-the-smallest-constant-that-has-explicitly-appeared-in-a-published-paper).

Comment: Are you asking for the smallest strictly positive number that has appeared in a reputable publication and has gained inexplicable publicity?

Comment: This one comes from physics, but still interesting, [planck's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant) $= 6.626\, 070 \times 10^{-34}$

Comment: The value of my trading account is another. It is so small it will fit in the margins.

Comment: Any infinitesimal element from [non-standard analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis) ;-)

Comment: @ReinerMartin the questions restricts to $\mathbb R^+$

Answer (score 1):

A number approximated as $1.14894×10^{-9}$ figures into the construction of the regular $65537$-gon.  It's the distance between the circumcircle and the in-circle, divided by the cirumradius.

Meaning that if you wanted to construct this polygon and allow $1$ mm distance to distinguish between the polygon and it's circumcircle with a good pencil, the polygon would have to extend more than the distance from New York to Chicago!